# Python SSL/TLS - no shared cipher on Python 3.8 but working on Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, ssl, openssl

My server can run on either Python 3.6 or Python 3.8. The problem seems to be the client.

If I run the client on Python 3.6, I get TLSv1.2 working with no error. But if I run the same client code on Python 3.8, I get NO_SHARED_CIPHER on the server and SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE on the client.

I suspect it has something to do with server or client certificate.

UPDATE: I created some new server and client certificates to experiment around with: `ed25519`, `rsa`, and `secp256k1`. From what I've seen, the problem above only shows up when the server certificate is `secp256k1` and both the client and server are running Python 3.8 (and therefore with TLSv1.3). The client can use any type of certificate.

Comment: This can mean that the server doesn't have a private key, which in turn means that it can't find a cipher suite, as all the secure ones require a private key.

Answer (score 0):

> ... NO_SHARED_CIPHER ...
>   I suspect it has something to do with server or client certificate.

This is a problem of cipher selection and cipher selection has almost nothing to do with the certificate, at least if the the certificate type is still the same, i.e. ECC vs. RSA. And I assume that you are still using the same certificate or at least the same certificate type in the working and non-working cases.

It is more likely that your client tries to use some RC4 or 3DES based cipher which is today considered obsolete and thus is no longer supported  by a server when using a newer version of the software stack (i.e. Python+OpenSSL).

Comment: It can also mean that the sever doesn't have a private key.

Comment: @user207421: Based on the question I assume that the same code and setup is used with different versions of Python. If the private key would be missing it would fail with both versions of Python. But you are right that one can get this kind of error also when certificates for the server side are not properly setup and thus only anonymous ciphers would be available.

Comment: @Myath: can you please create a packet capture of the working connection (Python 3.6) and the non-working one (Python 3.8) and provide it so that one can see all details of the ClientHello and the ServerHello? Do you have any more information about the client? The other main difference between Python 3.6 and  Python 3.8 that the latter supports TLS 1.3.